# How do I use asyncio.Lock to stop a function from running more than once concurrently?

Tags: python, concurrency, locking, python-asyncio

Looking into asyncio.Lock to stop a function from running at the same time as another. But am a little confused. Essentially what I need is for a cache update function to be locked if multiple requests are made to it at the same time (By the same user), or within close proximity of each other. This will prevent the external api from rate limiting this users token.

```py
app.ctx.cache = {} # {userToken: {user_information...}
app.route(user_information, "/api/user_information")

async def user_information(request):
  token = request.get("user_token")
  cooldown = 5
  last_update = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=cooldown) < app.ctx.cache.get(token).get("last_call")
  if not app.ctx.cache.get(token) or not last_update:
    update_cache()

  return app.ctx.cache.get(token)

async def update_caching(
    app,
    token,
    user_information=None,
):
  with asyncio.Lock(): # lock this function to prevent rate limit from external api
    if user_information:
      resp = await make_request("example.com...")
```

If the same user makes a request to this endpoint, I don't want this update cache function to be ran concurrently. Instead, the function should be `locked` until it has finished its first iteration. Should I be making a separate `asyncio.Lock()` inside of `user_information` (each route) and pass it into `update_caching()` as an arguement? Or should I just be using one `asyncio.Lock()` inside of `update_caching`? (Create the lock of the function instead)

Comment: You must share the same `asyncio.Lock` for every call to `update_caching`. If you create a new instance in every call, the function is using always an unlocked `asyncio.Lock`, so there isn't a shared resource between calls.

Comment: Oh okay. So esentially if I want a lock to be on a per user basis, I'd create a lock for a specific token and store that in their cache?

Comment: That's right, one per user.

Comment: Thanks very much Svex. This was literally 3 lines of code and now it works flawlessly.